# ClassNotFoundException on CloudResourceManager$Builder

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

In a spring boot application running google cloud dataflow code. The dataflow takes data from google PubSub, transform incoming data and output result to bigquery for storage. The code does not have any syntax errors. The problem is when the application is run, the following exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:52)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:142)
at com.trackers.exlon.ExlonApplication.main(ExlonApplication.java:69)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
... 4 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/services/cloudresourcemanager/CloudResourceManager$Builder
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.newCloudResourceManagerClient(GcpOptions.java:369)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:240)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:228)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:592)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:533)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:156)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.getGcpTempLocation(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:223)
... 9 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.services.cloudresourcemanager.CloudResourceManager$Builder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 17 more
```

As this is a spring boot maven project, instead of copy pasting POM file dependencies, i think below dependency tree will show more on dependencies and transitive dependencies as well, though if POM is needed i will switch this with POM file

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.ipc:reactor-netty:jar:0.7.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-multipart-parser:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-stream-storage:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-core:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:jar:0.33.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:jar:0.33.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api:api-common:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api:gax:jar:1.16.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.auto.value:auto-value:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.api:gax-httpjson:jar:0.33.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev347-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.instrumentation:instrumentation-api:jar:0.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.20.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.apis:google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager:jar:v1beta1-rev10-1.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-common-runner-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.16.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub:jar:v1-rev10-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-pubsub-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-proto-client:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-protobuf:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.datastore:datastore-v1-protos:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-common-protos:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:1.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:1.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.5.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:jar:1.2.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:jar:3.0.0-alpha-5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner:jar:0.33.0-beta:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-spanner-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-util:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-protos:jar:1.0.0-pre3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:1.0.0-pre3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-appengine:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1:jar:0.1.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-dataflow:jar:v1b3-rev213-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-clouddebugger:jar:v2-rev8-1.22.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev114-1.23.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:util:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.marineapi:marineapi:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.20:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.0.RC1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.0.RC1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.0.RC1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.13.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.9:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.9:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] \- io.projectreactor:reactor-test:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
```

What google cloud dataflow dependencies should i use for a pipeline to run successfuly.

Answer (score 2):

Add the newer version of the cloudresourcemanager to your POM.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev6-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Full explanation [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/442#issuecomment-367747053).

Answer (score 1):

Please use this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager</artifactId>
    <version>v1beta1-rev3-1.20.0</version>
```

Comment: When i add that dependency i get this error now `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineOptions`

Comment: Use this dependency

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency

Comment: Still, i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineOptions`

Comment: can you please check the downloaded dependencies in your project,is maven downloaded this dependency?.